# Expanding English contractions in, based on a dictionary of most common contractions

Tags: python, dictionary, twitter, preprocessor

I'm trying to substitute contracted words using Python, but am facing errors.

```
import re
tweet = "I luv my <3 iphone & you're awsm apple. DisplayIsAwesome, sooo happppppy  http://www.apple.com"
contractions_dict = {"ain't": "am not",
                  "aren't": "are not",
                  "can't": "cannot",
                  "you're": "you are"}    

contractions_re = re.compile('(%s)' '|'.join(contractions_dict.keys()))

def expand_contractions(s, contractions_dict=contractions_dict):
    def replace(match):
        return contractions_dict[match.group(0)]

    return contractions_re.sub(replace, s)

expand_contractions(tweet)
```

I've tried adding a "/" in the "you're", didn't work.

The output is supposed to be the expanded version, but instead the original tweet is just passed through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a clue:

```
>>> print('(%s)' '|'.join(contractions_dict.keys()))
you're(%s)|aren't(%s)|ain't(%s)|can't
```

Since `%s` has no particular meaning in a regex, it will simply match itself. But there is no percent sign in your input, so the match fails.

I suspect that you were looking for something like

```
>>> print('|'.join('(%s)' % k for k in contractions_dict.keys()))
(you're)|(aren't)|(ain't)|(can't)
```

Or perhaps

```
>>> print('(%s)' % '|'.join(contractions_dict.keys()))
(you're|aren't|ain't|can't)
```

But since you are using `match.group(0)` (i.e., the whole matched string) the captures are irrelevant, and there is no need to parenthesize the words in an alternation. So the simpler solution is fine:

```
>>> contractions_re = re.compile('|'.join(contractions_dict.keys()))
>>> expand_contractions(tweet)
'I luv my <3 iphone & you are awsm apple. DisplayIsAwesome, sooo happppppy \xf0\x9f\x99\x82 http://www.apple.com'
```